# XNA collision in 3D

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

I have been trying to get collision detection in my program. In my program there is a ball inside a cube. I want the ball bounce inside the cube, and if I have a hole in my cube I want it to fall out.

How I did 'collision' now is with this:

```
protected void Bounce()
    {
        if (ballPosition.X >= boxWidth || ballPosition.X <= -boxWidth)
            modelVelocity.X *= -1;
        if (ballPosition.Y >= boxHeight*4.18 || ballPosition.Y <= -boxHeight)
            modelVelocity.Y *= -1;
        if (ballPosition.Z >= boxLength || ballPosition.Z <= -boxLength)
            modelVelocity.Z *= -1;
    }
```

But this doesn't work very well and glitched when I implemented gravity. It goes throught the sides. It doesn't stay inside the box. So how does one detect collision and maybe also detect an angle so it bounces in a certain direction if there are slanted walls?

Comment: Where is ballPosition.X and .Y referencing? Those values cannot detect all of the edges of your sphere without using some sort of radius. Chances are the positions you mention above are actually the center of the sphere and what you're seeing are the edges clipping through.

You have to do the math to find the edge of the ball.

Answer (score 3):

To detect when the ball and box intersect, you could use a BoundingSphere and BoundingBox for each respectively. Then use the [BoudningBox.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195382.aspx) method and one of the different [Containment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.containmenttype.aspx) types to detect when the ball and box edges intersect.

Just as an example:

```
void CollisionDetection()
{
    if (!boxBoundingBox.Contains(ballBouningSphere, ContainmentType.Contains)) 
    //if the box doesn't completely contain the ball they are overlapping
    {
        //Collision happened.
    }
}
```

Then for holes, you might want to create a custom object `holes` that, if the ball and box overlap, checks to see if the ball is in the hole, and if so, cancel the collision. These are just some ideas. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Use the logic of axes: When the X > targetX and X < targetX + width --> X-axis collision confirmed.
But that doesn't mean that there's collision: You have to do the same for the Y-axis(and for 3D also the Z)
So you get:

```
public bool collision(Vector3 pos, Vector3 dimensions, Vector3 targetPos, 
Vector3 targetDimensions)
{
   return (pos.X + dimensions.X > targetPos.X &&
           pos.X < targetPos.X + targetDimensions.X &&
           pos.Y + dimensions.Y > targetPos.Y &&
           pos.Y < targetPos.Y + targetDimensions.Y &&
           pos.Z + dimensions.Z > targetPos.Z &&
           pos.Z < targetPos.Z + targetDimensions.Z);
}
```